# MySQL join two table with add one extra column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a two table. First one is a table1 and second one is a table2. I have attached both table image. I want to join into both table like UNION ALL operator. I need one extra column in table filed name is sid and this sid is work like a primary key. I have attached a image when i need my project. very sorry about my English. Thank you!

```
SELECT * FROM `table1`
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `table2`
```

[image]

**Table 1**

[image]

**Table 2**

I need a result like this image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example I can see that table1 rows sort before table2. In this case I add additional column to queries just for ordering purpose, and then forget about it later, when assigning `sid`. MySQL doesn't provide `row_number` window function, but there's a way to generate a sequence using a variable in query:

```
SELECT l.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS sid
FROM (
  SELECT t.id, t.name
  FROM (
    SELECT *, 1 as tbl_order FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 2 FROM table2
  ) t
  ORDER BY tbl_order
) l,
  (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

One subquery might be enough, but I can't try it out right now.